# PHP - Conexão remota MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Boa Tarde!

Estou montando um servidor para hospedar uma API, para meus testes de conexão estou utilizando o código a baixo, porem não consigo realizar a conexão ao banco de dados e nem ver qual o erro que o PHP retorna. Já procurei pela internet e não entendo o que está errado no meu código. Já consegui realizar conexão e escrita no banco com uma script Python.

```
<?PHP

# PHP 7
$conexao = mysqli_connect('187.182.164.73','Admin','SENHA');
$banco = mysqli_select_db($conexao,'pessoa');
mysqli_set_charset($conexao,'utf8');

$sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"select * from tb_pessoa") or die(error_reporting(E_ALL));
while($dados=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
    {
        echo $dados['nome'].'<br>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Utilize `mysqli_error` para verificar qual o erro.

Comment: Precisa mudar a senha urgentemente, seu DB está exposto na internet e você passou as credenciais na postagem.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função mysqli_connect_errno() para verificar qual é o erro de conexão ou a função mysqli_query() para descobrir qual o erro da query executada. Por exemplo na conexão faça isso:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('187.182.164.73','Admin','SENHA');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
```

Onde a função mysqli_connect_error() mostrará qual é o erro.

Na query executada faça assim:

```
if (!mysqli_query($conexao,"select * from tb_pessoa") or die(error_reporting(E_ALL)))) {
  print_r(mysqli_error_list($conexao));
}
```

Onde a função mysqli_error_list() mostrará o erro ao executar a query.

Assim você conseguirá ver quais são os erros no banco de dados.
Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score -1):

```
$servidor = "HOST";
$usuario = "USUARIO";
$senha = "SENHA";
$dbname = "DB_NAME";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_pessoa";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while($dados= mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
     echo "$dados['nome'] . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Se estiver usando apache, abre o php.ini você pode altear o "display_errors" de "Off" para "On".

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [Da Revisão](/review/low-quality-posts/275786)

Comment: @TiedtTech, quando fizer uma recomendação de exclusão de resposta e texto sugerido não se enquadrar ao caso use a primeira opção  `Não são necessários comentários` e fica ao seu critério voltar a resposta e deixar um comentário ao AR.